# How to filter the result from comparing a XML & XSD?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I'm comparing one XML & one XSD collection in WPF with TreeViewItem.
I finally got the missing result to show in red. 
But how to filter the result from XSD collection to a listbox, so that it can show only the lines(values) which are in red  ?

```
private void CompareTrees(ItemCollection xml, ItemCollection xsd, List<string> path)
    {
        foreach (TreeViewItem tvixsd in xsd.OfType<TreeViewItem>())
        {
            path.Add(tvixsd.Header.ToString());

            if (tvixsd.HasItems)
            {
                CompareTrees(xml, tvixsd.Items, path);
            }
            else
            {
                TreeViewItem res = xml.OfType<TreeViewItem>().FirstOrDefault();
                foreach (var point in path.Skip(1))
                {
                    res = res.Items.OfType<TreeViewItem>().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Header.ToString() == point);
                    if (res == null)
                    {                            
                        treeViewCom.Items.Add(res);
                        tvixsd.Foreground = Brushes.Red;

                        break;
                    }

                    if (!res.HasItems)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (path.Count != 0)
            {
                path.RemoveAt(path.Count - 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Sort what collection of items?

Comment: the xsd item collection

Comment: Where and how are you displaying this in your UI?

Comment: treeviews are for xml and xsd files and result for listbox https://ufile.io/g79x6

Comment: Do you mean sort or filter?

Comment: filter...because i actually want to remove data that’s irrelevant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148608/discussion-between-batbaqna-and-mm8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Filter` property of the `ItemsCollection`:

```
xsd.Filter = (obj) =>
{
    TreeViewItem tvi = obj as TreeViewItem;
    return tvi != null && tvi.Foreground == Brushes.Red;
};
```

Comment: Am I or anyone else supposed to know "error with tvixsd" actually means...?

Comment: i mean when i change tvixsd with the tvi from your code i get an error on my if (!res.HasItems)

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

res was null."

Comment: Change tvixsd? I haven't suggested this. Add my code *after* your foreach (TreeViewItem tvixsd in xsd.OfType<TreeViewItem>()) loop.

Comment: Are you sure that there are ny items with a Foreground of Red then? Only these are shown when you apply the filter.

Comment: i had to put the code after the second foreach(not the first one) ! it's all good now, thanks a lot !